# On iOS, if the plist says "Landscape Left", and shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation says LandscapeRight, the app can start with Portrait mode?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I wonder why, if a Single View app is created brand new for iPad, and clicking on the Project, I chose in "Support Device Orientation" to be `Landscape Left`, and in ViewController's `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`, I return `YES` only when it is `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight`, then the app can actually start up as Portrait mode?

I more expected the app to start up as `Landscape Left` and be able to rotate to `Landscape Right` and then won't be able to rotate to any other orientation.  I wonder what caused the above behavior?

Comment: Are you sure the portrait orientation is not selected in the project settings? You can choose more than one there.